# Differences between EER and UML

Tags: mysql, database, uml, erd, eer-model

I've downloaded MySQL workbench and can create a EER diagram.

What's the difference between this and a UML diagram?

Where does a ERD come into this?

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680231/differences-between-a-conceptual-uml-class-diagram-and-an-erd) help?

Answer (score 5):

I think by UML diagram you mean : UML Class Diagram. [ there are other UML diagrams also]

**EER (Enhanced entity–relationship) Diagram-Model**

**Used for Database Design**. Like class diagrams support also subclass -superclass [specialization and generalization]. **So entities in EER diagrams has attributes not methods**.Because **they show  just plain data**.

Note:  ER [entity–relationship] Diagrams are origin of EER. They are from Structured Analysis. Also used for database modeling.How ER become to EER? I think because of Object Oriented Style Hype.

**UML Class Diagrams**

**Used for Object Oriented Analysis-Design.**

*Can be used  to model databases also :  there are UML class profiles for it.*
[I think UML profiles for Database Designs are NOT good as ER diagrams]

But in simple terms classes are  blueprints in which objects instantinated . **So classes  may have methods-functions as well as attributes**.Software classes definitely has methods but conceptual classes[ used for domain modeling] may not.

Comment: The extra E has to do with a few added features, notably generalization/specialization, e.g. a pet can be a dog or a cat or a bird, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between ERD and UML is that ERD stands for Entity Relationship Diagram, a type of diagram (as explained above), while UML stands for Uniform Modeling Language, which is essentially a standard defining a modeling language commonly used in software development, especially in Object Oriented Program.

UML also proposes standard diagram types (as noted above), usually grouped into structural or behavioral diagrams. Most DB GUIs use ERDs, which are better suited for the domain and most users don't need formal, academic diagrams.

Note that most software teams like to site UML as a reference; yet, don't usually implement UML to full spec or with academic rigor when creating documentation diagrams.

As a rule of thumb, if you want to model DB entities/relationships you are probably looking for an ERD but if you want to model an entire program/system then you probably need one-many of the different UML diagrams.