# How do you model Database-to-Database integration/mapping in UML?

Tags: database, architecture, uml

I'm working on a project where we have to take fields from one database and map them to fields on another database and log the transformations e.g. field Name from one database would be split by the space and stored in the fields First_Name and Last_Name in another database. I was wondering how you would do this in UML. I am new to UML, so please excuse me if my vocabulary is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process. There are several tools specific for ETL and most have their own graphic way to visualize the transformations. These tools are data-centric, and even more generic database tools might do the job for you as @observer suggested.

I wouldn't use UML for describing an ETL process, but if you decide to to give it a try, you can find some papers on the net about it like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/whitepapers/modelling-of-data-extraction-in-etl-processes-using-uml-20/390056) or [this](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-88875-8_21).

If you develop the ETL process with an object oriented language, then you could follow a typical UML design approach:

1. Use class diagrams to visualize the database structures. Each table corresponds to a class, the class diagram will show the same information as an ERD as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680231/differences-between-a-conceptual-uml-class-diagram-and-an-erd).
2. Visualize the class that makes the transformation with one or more class diagrams.
3. Describe the transformation logic with activity diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a database-specific modeling tool for that kind of task. Something like the [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Which software is exactly the best for your case is of course vendor specific.